# How to run project in Angular 4/expressJS server directly(without webpack)

Tags: node.js, angular, express, webpack

for now I exec 'ng build' and exec 'ts-node ./src/index.ts':

```js
//////////index.ts
    import * as express from 'express';
    import { join } from 'path';
    import { json, urlencoded }from 'body-parser';
    import BaseRoutes = require("./backend/services/newService");

    var app : any = express();

    app.use(express.static(join(__dirname + '/../dist/')));
    app.use(json());
    app.use(urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.use('/api', new BaseRoutes().routes);
    app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
     res.sendFile(join(__dirname + '/../index.html'));
    });
    app.listen(3000);
```

all good and work, but How to run only expressJS server, compile project by using original files only (without webpack).

in case of pushing on prod I compile project by compressed /dist/files only, otherwise I would like to work with original files

**varibale __dirname is**

```
C:\Users\AxOn\Documents\projects\techStarters\ang4Express\src
```

Help please

if I exec just 'ts-node ./src/index.ts' and change path as __dirname + '/index.html' I see white Display:
[image]

seems angular is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

in your package.json

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "start": "node ./server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {...
```

then in your project directory at the command line do;

```
npm start
```

npm will execute whatever is in start section of your package.json file

Comment: I tried, server ran succsesfully but I see white page, seems angular is not loaded. Edited this post above

Comment: If angular is not loaded the browser will let you know about it, if you are using chrome which it looks like from your screenshot then in the console tab in developer tools it will have all sorts of errors.